# How to create customizable SharePoint page for users

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

How do you create customizable home pages for users on SharePoint?  I would like to allow users to have "tiles/widgets" similar to my.yahoo.com where each tile can be personalized, dragged/re-arranged around by the each user of the site.  Thanks,

Comment: You cannot with the OOTB features. You need to develop a custom solution.

Comment: Can anyone point me to a possible open source custom solution we may be able to utilize?

Comment: Did you check my site in SharePoint(Not sure if it satisfies your req.)
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-My-Site-2f2b071a-1444-4a6f-ae73-4892b0a55449